# Unresolved functions or methods using CodeceptJS in PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, webstorm, webdriver-io, codeceptjs

I've just followed the [CodeceptJS Quickstart](http://codecept.io/quickstart/) and opened `first_test.js` in the PhpStorm IDE (equivalent to WebStorm, IntelliJ, etc.).

For all the built-in functions, I'm getting "Unresolved function or method …":

[image]

I also don't get any autocompletion on `I`.

I've tried the following.

1. Looked for a CodeceptJS plugin. Didn't find any.
2. Enabled `codeceptjs/node_modules` in Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> JavaScript -> Libraries.
3. Set JavaScript language version to ECMAScript 6.
4. Enabled the Node.js Core library.
5. Restarted PhpStorm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please run 'npm install codeceptjs'.

Comment: Great, thanks. I find it a bit strange that this makes a difference, considering that I have installed `codeceptjs-webdriverio` which in turn depends on `codeceptjs`.

Comment: @YngveHøiseth As I understand it's the way how IDE is indexing the `node_modules` -- it only indexes modules that YOU are required (in your `package.json` or whatever that file is) and ignores packages (excludes folders) if they are not used directly (e.g. used by other libs internally). This is to avoid polluting completion with most-likely-unneeded-for-you libs/functions (since they may be used only inside that lib). If you need something -- require it directly (make it your direct dependency).

Comment: This does not fix the problem. The functions are not imported and phpstorm will still think they are non existant

Answer (score 0):

I had to follow the steps outlined in https://codecept.io/typescript/ to fully enable CodeceptJS in PHPStorm.

**Steps**

1. `npm install codeceptjs typescript ts-node`
2. Add `require('ts-node/register')` as first line in my `codecept.conf.js` file
3. Create a `tsconfig.json` in my project root folder
4. Run `npx codeceptjs def` to create the default `steps.d.ts` file

After that, autocompletion worked in my tests :)